# How to trigger change even with autoChecking a checkbox

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

I have a change even that filters a table. i want to make 3 of the checkbox auto check from input I'm getting from the client in a different page.

everything is working correctly but when i put `checked="true"` the checkbox is checked but the `change` event is not triggered only when i unchecked the checkbox i was getting a trigger.

This is my HTML check box :

```
<mat-checkbox  class="CheckBoxClass" value="clientType" (change)="updateFilter('LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR', clientType)" >{{clientType}}</mat-checkbox>
```

If anything else is needed to answer this question i will provide it.

I don't have a working stackblitz of this project.

Comment: What do you mean? Check this: [working as expected](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7kjcx) Do you need that event to be triggerd on initial value

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i have a checkbox that is filtering data. but i want it to filter the data without me clicking on it. that's why i tried 'checked' and it didn't work as intended. it did checked the checkbox but didn't trigger the event

Comment: yes got it....!

Comment: Check this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7kjcx have triggered the event manually in the constructor